# access react sub sub sub component ref

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Is there an elegant way or react functionality that will enable the parent component to access sub component ref? I need to link the button in the parent component to the inputbox in the sub component. The sub component ref that I'm trying to access is kinda deep, see the structure below, and i don't want to use props to pass down the ref.

Any suggestion on how to handle this? TIA!

```
Parent Component (with button to clear the inputbox)
|_ Sub component
   |_ Sub component
     |_ Sub component 
        |_ Inputbox component
```

Comment: Why do you need a ref to begin with? Clearing the inputbox should be done through state update.

Comment: @super to clear/focus on the input box when a button is pressed on the parent component.